# CheckBoxList inserting in SQL code

Tags: vb.net, checkboxlist

> Hello, need your help in determine what is the wrong in this code,
>   this used to fill a sql db from checkboxlist multiple selection but
>   not giving the needed result.
>
> I need to save every selection on a column in the same row but when
>   run this every time it gives the same below result

```
field_1  field_2  field_3  id

test2     test3   test4    1
```

> even am selected values (test 5, test 6, test 7) not (test 2, test 3,
>   test 4) from cbl.
>
> your help is highly appreciated :)

### Test.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

' Define data objects
        Dim myConn As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim sqlstring As String

        ' Read the connection string 
        myConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EmailEngineDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

        ' Create command
        sqlstring = " INSERT INTO TestTBL (field_1, field_2, field_3) VALUES (@field_1, @field_2, @field_3)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlstring, myConn)

        ' Add command parameters
        For i As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
            If CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Selected Then


                cmd.Parameters.Add("@field_" + i.ToString(), Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
                cmd.Parameters("@field_" + i.ToString()).Value = CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Text
            End If

        Next
        ' Enclose database code in Try-Catch-Finally
        Try
            ' Open the connection
            myConn.Open()
            ' Execute the command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' Display success message
            Label1.Text = "Created Successfully :)"
            ' Reload page if the query executed successfully
            ' Response.Redirect("SamplesCollector.aspx")

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Display error message
            Label1.Text = "Error ! Please try again "
        Finally
            ' Close the connection
            myConn.Close()
            'Response.Redirect("SamplesCollector.aspx")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

---

Test.aspx

---

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem>test 1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test 3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test 4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test 5</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test 6</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test 7</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test 8</asp:ListItem>

        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database table only accommodates three field values.

The query:

```
INSERT INTO TestTBL (field_1, field_2, field_3) VALUES (@field_1, @field_2, @field_3)
```

Only contains three parameters (`@field_1`, `@field_2` and `@field_3`).

So, in your loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Selected Then


            cmd.Parameters.Add("@field_" + i.ToString(), Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
            cmd.Parameters("@field_" + i.ToString()).Value = CheckBoxList1.Items(i).Text
        End If

    Next
```

Despite the fact that this will (given your checklist definition) iterate over 8 items, only    "**test2**", "**test 3**" and "**test 4**" will ever get passed to the database, when they are selected.

This is because their position in the checklist matches the name of your parameter (i.e. "**test2**" is item number 1 (zero-based list) and will match to `@field_1`).

In order to store all selected options, you really should change the database table structure to allow an arbitrary number of items.  At worst, you need to add additional columns to the table to account for the rest of the available checklist items (up to a `field_8`, and you also need to account for the fact that the first item in the list has an index of 0 and not 1.

For example, create a one-to-many relationship between the Question and a SelectedOptions table.

**Question:**

```
QuestionId | UserId
1          | 1
```

**SelectedOptions:**

```
SelectedOptionId | QuestionId | SelectedValue
1                | 1          | test2
2                | 1          | test 3
```

Your insert loop would then insert a record into `SelectedOptions` for each value that was checked.  You can then support an arbitrary number of selected options.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, could you plz advise me with the best practice for execute this .. inserting the selected CheckBoxList values into a SQL db ?Knowing that when try to add additional columns in the database to fit the checklist items (up to a field_8) it didn't work anymore

Comment: gr8 logic thank you very much :) appreciate your help